# How much logic should I handle via JSR 303 / Bean Validation?

Tags: playframework-2.0, bean-validation

I have a Play 2.0.1 app and am just getting the hang of the form handling via the spring data binder, as [described in the documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaForms). I got to the point where I hava a form, let's say a user sends a message to another user, looking something like this:

```
public class MessageForm {

  @NotNull @NotEmpty
  public String message;

  @NotNull
  public User recipient;

  // i know, no sender
}
```

My custom binder makes sure that the user, which is represented by his id in the HTML-form, gets correctly serialized and would default to null when no such user exists.

I am thinking about writing additional validation, i.E. for making sure the user passed via the form is friends with the user trying to post the message. This would basically be a sort of `@FriendsWithCurrentUser`-Annotation.

I know how to do just that, my question would be: is this a good idea? From a module point of view this would be a constraint that is somewhat rooted in the web context, so I wouldn't want to put it in my models-Package. I have the vague feeling this might not be what the JSR is meant for, but I also think this would greatly reduce the logic in my controllers and allow me to reuse similar constraints on user submissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the common problem. The other similar case is validations which must talk to database.

From my point of view the question is how often are you going to use that validation? If it is something that will be used in 20 places I would write annotation + validator class, but if this validation is used in one or two places it is better to manually throw ConstraintViolationException. Then we are still using common validation mechanism, but we don't need to write questionable validator class. Sometimes this is also performance issue: we query database just for the sake of validation and that query is often repeated in bussiness logic.

The trade-off is between having well separated validation from the rest of the code versus validator which is mixing various application layers.

Usually I prefer to write separate validation since it often occurs that the same validation has to be used elsewhere. Without separate validator I often duplicate existing validation code since there is always something more important to do then refactor validation...

The idea of Bean Validation is to have separate layer in application, which is responsible for validation. That layer should not be mixed with Model, since a given Model can be validated in many different ways.

There could be one Model and various sets of validators - annotations are just the configuration. Sometimes, if Model is going to be used in various products, it is even better to give up annotations at all and use XML-based configuration (it is suprisingly easy to comprehend and use).

So don't put validators in Model package, create a new package for your validators, if you want to go that way.